# Hive SQL: How to subset groups of records by max time

Tags: datetime, hadoop, hive, hiveql, cloudera

I have records grouped by ID1 and ID2 such as the following:

```
ID1      ID2         date_time
Apple pear         2020-03-09T12:11:25:622Z
Apple pear         2020-03-09T12:23:36:825Z
Apple lemon        2020-03-08T08:01:16:030Z
Apple lemon        2020-03-09T10:11:12:930Z
Apple lemon        2020-03-09T15:13:02:610Z
Lime  peach        2020-03-09T07:34:06:825Z
Lime peach         2020-03-09T07:54:12:220Z
Melon banana       2020-03-09T03:54:11:041Z
Melon banana       2020-03-09T09:22:10:220Z
Orange pear        2020-03-09T11:13:36:217Z
Orange pear        2020-03-09T11:23:26:040Z
Orange pear        2020-03-09T11:43:35:721Z
```

I'm trying to extract records that has a maximum record passing a time frame, such that if I want to extract records with max time no greater than noon on March 9th, the above records will be subsetted to:

```
ID1      ID2         date_time
Lime  peach        2020-03-09T07:34:06:825Z
Lime peach         2020-03-09T07:54:12:220Z
Melon banana       2020-03-09T03:54:11:041Z
Melon banana       2020-03-09T09:22:10:220Z
Orange pear        2020-03-09T11:13:36:217Z
Orange pear        2020-03-09T11:23:26:040Z
Orange pear        2020-03-09T11:43:35:721Z
```

I used `cast(regexp_replace('2020-03-09T16:05:06:827Z','(.*?)T(.*?):([^:]*?)Z$','$1 $2\\.$3') as timestamp)` to convert the date_time to timestamp thanks to @leftjoin.

Appreciate for any help.

Added vertex issue occurred after sub-setting by time:

Note: I'm only allowed to make temporary table.

First: I dedup the raw dataset by ID1 and ID2

```
 create temporary table data1 as 
select id1, id2, name, value,
       cast(regexp_replace(oldtime,'(.*?)T(.*?):([^:]*?)Z$','$1 $2\\.$3') as timestamp) as date_time
       from (
        select ID1, ID2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id1, id2,name, value ORDER BY value) as rn,
        case when name like '%_TIME' then value end as date_time
        from df.data1
         )undup

        where undup.rn = 1 AND 
        value <> '' and value is not null
        order by ID1, ID2, date_time ASC
```

then  I subset by time:

```
create temporary table data2 as
    select *
     from(
     select *,
           max(date_time) over (partition by id1,id2) as max_date
      from data1
      ) s

      where max_date <= '2020-03-12 12:00:00'
```

After this I get a vertex error..

```
 ERROR: Execute error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1583806821840_6890_2_01, 
        diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1583806821840_6890_2_01_000036, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error 
        while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1583806821840_6890_2_01_000036_0:java.lang.RuntimeException: 
        java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:296) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:250) at 
        org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374) at 
        org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73) at 
        org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61) at 
        java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730) at 
        org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61) at 
        org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37) at 
        org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36) at 
        com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenab
        leFutureTask.java:108) at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:41) at 
        com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:77) at 
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at 
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at 
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource.pushRecord(ReduceRecordSource.java:304) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordProcessor.run(ReduceRecordProcessor.java:318) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:267) ... 16 moreCaused by: 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource$GroupIterator.next(ReduceRecordSource.java:378) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource.pushRecord(ReduceRecordSource.java:294) ... 18 moreCaused by: 
        java.lang.NullPointerException at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.PTFRowContainer.first(PTFRowContainer.java:115) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.PTFPartition.iterator(PTFPartition.java:114) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.ptf.BasePartitionEvaluator.getPartitionAgg(BasePartitionEvaluator.java:200) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.ptf.WindowingTableFunction.evaluateFunctionOnPartition(WindowingTableFunction.java:155) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.ptf.WindowingTableFunction.iterator(WindowingTableFunction.java:538) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.PTFOperator$PTFInvocation.finishPartition(PTFOperator.java:349) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.PTFOperator.process(PTFOperator.java:123) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.baseForward(Operator.java:994) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:940) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:927) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:95) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource$GroupIterator.next(ReduceRecordSource.java:363) ... 19 more], 
        TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : 
        attempt_1583806821840_6890_2_01_000036_1:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:296) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:250) at 
        org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374) at 
        org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73) at 
        org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61) at 
        java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730) at 
        org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61) at 
        org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37) at 
        org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36) at 
        com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenab
        leFutureTask.java:108) at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:41) at 
        com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:77) at 
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at 
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at 
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource.pushRecord(ReduceRecordSource.java:304) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordProcessor.run(ReduceRecordProcessor.java:318) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:267) ... 16 moreCaused by: 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource$GroupIterator.next(ReduceRecordSource.java:378) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource.pushRecord(ReduceRecordSource.java:294) ... 18 moreCaused by: 
        java.lang.NullPointerException at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.PTFRowContainer.first(PTFRowContainer.java:115) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.PTFPartition.iterator(PTFPartition.java:114) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.ptf.BasePartitionEvaluator.getPartitionAgg(BasePartitionEvaluator.java:200) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.ptf.WindowingTableFunction.evaluateFunctionOnPartition(WindowingTableFunction.java:155) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.ptf.WindowingTableFunction.iterator(WindowingTableFunction.java:538) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.PTFOperator$PTFInvocation.finishPartition(PTFOperator.java:349) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.PTFOperator.process(PTFOperator.java:123) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.baseForward(Operator.java:994) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:940) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:927) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:95) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource$GroupIterator.next(ReduceRecordSource.java:363) ... 19 more], 
        TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : 
        attempt_1583806821840_6890_2_01_000036_2:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:296) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:250) at 
        org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374) at 
        org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use max analytic function and filter by it:

```
with your_data as (
select stack (12,
'Apple', 'pear'      ,  '2020-03-09T12:11:25:622Z',
'Apple', 'pear'      ,  '2020-03-09T12:23:36:825Z',
'Apple', 'lemon'     ,  '2020-03-08T08:01:16:030Z',
'Apple', 'lemon'     ,  '2020-03-09T10:11:12:930Z',
'Apple', 'lemon'     ,  '2020-03-09T15:13:02:610Z',
'Lime',  'peach'     ,  '2020-03-09T07:34:06:825Z',
'Lime', 'peach'      ,  '2020-03-09T07:54:12:220Z',
'Melon', 'banana'    ,  '2020-03-09T03:54:11:041Z',
'Melon', 'banana'    ,  '2020-03-09T09:22:10:220Z',
'Orange','pear'      , '2020-03-09T11:13:36:217Z',
'Orange','pear'      , '2020-03-09T11:23:26:040Z',
'Orange','pear'      , '2020-03-09T11:43:35:721Z'
) as (ID1,ID2,date_time)
)
select ID1,ID2,date_time
from
(
select max(timestamp(regexp_replace(date_time,'(.*?)T(.*?):([^:]*?)Z$','$1 $2\\.$3'))) over (partition by ID1,ID2) as max_date,
       ID1,ID2,timestamp(regexp_replace(date_time,'(.*?)T(.*?):([^:]*?)Z$','$1 $2\\.$3')) as date_time
  from your_data 
)s 
where max_date<='2020-03-09 12:00:00'
```

Result:

```
id1     id2     date_time
Lime    peach   2020-03-09 07:54:12.22
Lime    peach   2020-03-09 07:34:06.825
Melon   banana  2020-03-09 09:22:10.22
Melon   banana  2020-03-09 03:54:11.041
Orange  pear    2020-03-09 11:43:35.721
Orange  pear    2020-03-09 11:23:26.04
Orange  pear    2020-03-09 11:13:36.217
```

Comment: Hi @leftjoin, I believe this code is what I'm looking for, but the size of the dataset I'm dealing with has over a million records, and whenever I subset id1+id2 by time in a subquery, I would receive a vertex fail error. Is this something I can avoid by altering the code? Or do I need to work with my database admin?

Comment: just updated my question with the vertex fail problem

Comment: @lydias You can remove timestamp transformation and compare with '2020-03-09T12:00:00:000Z' in the where clause. Your timestamp format will work fine with max() also. But I am not sure that it will help much. I do not see how this problem related to the code. Also 1M records is not a big deal... It may be something else. Try to solve with admins if this does not help

Comment: I will accept the answer. Thank you so much. Will need to talk to system admin to discuss about the memory issue.

Comment: @lydias It is NullPointerException, not memory issue. It may be some bug in your Hive version. See this jira: HIVE-18786 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-18786 and try to apply tez.am.container.reuse.enabled=false

Comment: But it will run if I test it on smaller dataset